# What is the difference between error, stderr, stdout in node

Tags: node.js, bash, error-handling, stdout, stderr

I am using node.js and want to handle error messages.
What are the differences between erro, stderr, stdout?

When scripting shell, I redirected stderr and found useful error message and it solved the problem.

I am not clear about the concept of what kind of outputs computer have either. Can anyone explain in a comprehensive way?

Thanks.

Comment: Standard streams on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams

Comment: This question is not so broad and this kind of question will help people new to linux environment.

Comment: Google can help people new to Linux. So can Wikipedia. Have you read the last paragraph of the question?

Comment: Also, mind you, there's nothing Linux specific here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stderr` and `stdout` are streams.  Writing to console will log both streams.  Apparently the distinction exists between them so we that if we want to (for example) redirect certain data elsewhere, we have the ability to be selective.

You may find the following article helpful.

http://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/7766119-when-to-use-stderr-instead-of-stdout

Answer (score 24):

It is actually an interesting question. You would probably get more answers if you format the title of your question like this -- Node JS difference between error, stderr, and stdout. 
I won't repeat the difference between stdout and stderr, as it is answered previously.

However, the difference between error and stderr is not that easily distinguished.

**Error** is an error object created by Node JS because it is having a problem executing your command. See more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)

**Stderr** is a standard output stream that happens because something is wrong during execution -- that is Node JS has no trouble executing your command, it is your command itself throws the error.

Let me know if this is clear, otherwise, I'm happy to throw in an example:)